# Executing my code during when ajax is in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Given my below code Is there a way i can get alert when my ajax process is still in progress?
as you have already noticed code for alert will never get executed because of obvious reason that async ajax will keep happening but the value of click false will come before that and i will never be able to get alert during ajax call. Is there any way i can get alert when ajax request still in process?

```
<html>
    <body>
    <button type="button" id="submit-catalog" class="btn btn-primary">Activate</button>
    </body>
    </html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
        clicked = true;
        //doing some ajax call which is taking time
    });
    if(clicked){ // never get executed
        alert("button clicked")
        //i am executing some function only if that button clicked
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to move `var clicked;` outside, then you need to assign a proper click handler to your button. Right now, `if (clicked)` runs when the document has finished loading, then never again. This is not an AJAX progress problem, this is a basic code logic problem.

Comment: before the ajax call you can put a alert to start the ajax and after ajax you can put a alert  ajax end so you can understand the mid time is in process

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Ajax. Code is getting executed top to bottom, you declared event listener on the document and it waits for action, while your 'if' statement was already processed.

This 'Alert' or any other action should be done within event listener

Also, if you want to do any action before executing ajax request you simply use `beforeSend: ()=>{/*your actions*/}`, and then after ajax request is done `success: callback=>{/*do when done*/}`
which may look like that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  beforeSend: ()=> { alert('clicked') },
  success: callback=> { console.log(callback) }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is off; here's how to do this:

```js
var clicked;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
    if (clicked) {
      console.log("ajax still in progress");
      return false;
    }
    clicked = true;
    console.log("starting ajax");
    setTimeout(function () {
      clicked = false;
      console.log("ajax done");
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="submit-catalog" class="btn btn-primary">Activate</button>
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this will prevent the ajax from firing again and again based on the variable which keeps track of the ajax progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use : `one()` instead of `on()` only if you don't use the `clicked` variable somewhere else. You attach the event for only one trigger. At the end of the callback you reattach it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function foo(e){
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("ajax done");
      $(e.delegateTarget).one('click', '#submit-catalog', foo)
    },1000)
  }

  $(document).one('click', '#submit-catalog', foo);
});
```

Other solution : add class to stop the propagation thanks to delegate event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document)
     .on('click', '#submit-catalog.prevent', function(e){
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     }
     .on('click', '#submit-catalog', function(){
       $(e.currentTarget).addClass('prevent');
       setTimeout(function () {
         console.log("ajax done");
         $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('prevent');
       }, 1000)
   });
});
```